# VHDL - Increment with one (unsigned)

Tags: encoding, vhdl, counter, increment, fpga

I'm trying to make a code that will increment the incoming bits with one. I want to use two-segment code styling, but the issue here is that the bits don't reach the output. Any idea? Thanks!

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.numeric_std.ALL;


entity increment1 is
    port(
        from_ASMD_State_reg : in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
        reset, clk : in std_logic;
        to_mux : out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)
    );
end increment1;

architecture Behavioral of increment1 is
--signal count : unsigned(7 downto 0);
signal r_reg : unsigned(7 downto 0);
signal r_next : unsigned(7 downto 0);
begin
process(clk, reset)
begin
    if(reset = '1') then
        to_mux <= (others => '0');
    elsif(clk'event and clk = '1') then
        r_reg <= r_next;
    end if;
end process;

r_next <= r_reg + 1;

to_mux <= std_logic_vector(r_reg);

end Behavioral;
```

After some adjustments in code, it seems like it's working now!

```
architecture Behavioral of increment1 is
signal r_reg : unsigned(7 downto 0);
signal r_inc : unsigned(7 downto 0);
begin
process(clk, reset, r_reg)
begin
    r_reg <= unsigned(from_ASMD_State_reg);

    if(reset = '1') then
        r_reg <= (others => '0');
    elsif(clk'event and clk = '1') then
        r_reg <= r_inc;
    end if;
end process;

r_inc <= r_reg + 1;

to_mux <= std_logic_vector(r_inc);

end Behavioral;
```

Comment: The `from_ASMD_State_reg` is not used in the module, so if that is the input to increment, then use it for a start.  Also, note that `to_mux` is both driven in the process, and outside the process, and such multiple drivers can't synthesize, and is likely to generate X's in simulation; intention is probably to drive `r_reg` in process.  Finally, you can do without `r_next` if `r_reg + 1` is used directly in the process expression.

Comment: @MortenZilmer Thank you for the reply. Just wondering how should I use from_ASMD_State_reg for a start? Should I set the r_reg to from_ASMD_State_reg? And where should I do it? :)

Comment: It really depends on the functionality you want to implement, so for a start make a specification for example a table, that lists the expected output for all the different input values, and in that process you are likely to understand what functionality you must implement in the design.

Comment: @MortenZilmer I did some changes, and pasted the code to my post. Can you please have a look at my code and see if I still have something stupid in my code? :)

Comment: You probably shouldn't be assigning to `r_reg` inside the process but outside the `if` block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your updated code is *almost* correct, but not quite. If all you want to do is increment and register a value, all you need is this:

```
architecture Behavioral of increment1 is
begin

  r_inc <= unsigned(from_ASMD_State_reg) + 1;

  process (clk, reset)
  begin
    if(reset = '1') then
        r_reg <= (others => '0');
    elsif(clk'event and clk = '1') then
        r_reg <= r_inc;
    end if;
  end process;

  to_mux <= std_logic_vector(r_reg);

end Behavioral;
```

*(note: edited the above to fix an assignment mistake and reorder the statements to make the desired "two segment style" more obvious)*

Are you sure it "works" with the assignment to `r_reg` inside your process but outside the if block? Have you tried to synthesize, or only simulate?

Optimizations:

- You can get rid of `r_inc` by putting the increment statement directly into the `r_reg` assignment in the process.
- You can get rid of `r_reg` by replacing it with `to_mux` in the process and typecasting.

You don't need all those intermediate signals for this operation. If you need them for other functions you want to add, feel free to keep them, but just be aware that the ports can be used in these operations - you don't need to assign them to another signal first.

The simplified assignment in your process would then be:

```
to_mux <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(from_ASMD_State_reg) + 1);
```

It's barely worth making a separate component to do this, but you can, of course.